# How can I remove \n and \r\n from stdout in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
import sys

HOST="cacamaca.caca"
COMMAND="display mac-address 0123-4567-8910"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result
```

Because the output has spaces and different lines, it prints carriage returns and new lines too so the result isn't a clean one:

['\r\n', 'cacamaca.caca\r\n', 'Info: The max number of VTY users is 10, and the number\r\n', '      of current VTY users on line is 2.\r\n', '      The current login time is 2017-07-20 20:10:54+03:00 DST.\r\n', '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n', 'MAC Address    VLAN/VSI                          Learned-From        Type      \r\n', '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n', '0123-4567-8910 1234/-                            Eth-Trunk9          dynamic   \r\n', '\r\n', '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\r\n', 'Total items displayed = 1 \n', '\r\n', '']

How can I remove '\n' and '\r\n' or at least replace them with spaces so that the result looks like the original one? I did read a lot of answers about this, but none helped.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Can you [edit] your question and include an example of what you want the output to look like?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `result` variable is a list. I think you want to join the results into a single string and print that. You can do that with `str.join()` like this

```
print ''.join(result)
```

This will result in the following output

```
cacamaca.caca
Info: The max number of VTY users is 10, and the number
 of current VTY users on line is 2.
 The current login time is 2017-07-20 20:10:54+03:00 DST.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MAC Address VLAN/VSI Learned-From Type
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0123-4567-8910 1234/- Eth-Trunk9 dynamic

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total items displayed = 1
```

Comment: thank you so much. just tested it. it worked great and i understood the problem perfectly :D

Comment: tried upvote but i'm on low rep yet. under 15. I accepted the answer. tnx again for everything

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.strip()` to remove new line characters, or `.replace()` to replace them, for example:

```
result = [x.strip() for x in result]
```

output:

```
['', 'cacamaca.caca', 'Info: The max number of VTY users is 10, and the number', 'of current VTY users on line is 2.', 'The current login time is 2017-07-20 20:10:54+03:00 DST.', '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------', 'MAC Address VLAN/VSI Learned-From Type', '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------', '0123-4567-8910 1234/- Eth-Trunk9 dynamic', '', '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------', 'Total items displayed = 1', '', '']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can remove '\n' and '\r\n' by using the following code.

```
with subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND], shell=False) as ssh:
        result = ssh.communicate()[0]
        print(result)
```